# I have 2 androidmanifestfile.xml and I deleted one, and this error shows up, "Cannot read packageName from

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have 2 androidmanifestfile.xml and I deleted one, and this error shows up, "Cannot read packageName from...." how to solve it? I want to make the last one (which I left) make it the main AndroidManifestFile but I don't know how to do it?

Comment: clarify your question with code samples

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it okay for you to show me the project structure?If there is one project for application, usually there should be one AndroidManifest file.But you said you had two manifest files.I guess you might had two projects: application and library. In this case, you must ensure you delete the library's manifest file .and in the manifest file you left, you need to assign the "package" property like this code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.your.package.name">
</manifest>
```